# Why are there two root and nobody accounts according to "getent passwd"?

Tags: ubuntu, passwd, getent

The output further down was retrieved by employing `machinectl` on a Ubuntu 20.04 host:

- `machinectl pull-tar https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/focal/current/focal-server-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.xz focal`
- `machinectl start focal`
- `systemd-run --machine focal --pty /bin/bash`

You should be able to reproduce this as long as the cloud image for "focal" is available.

Here's the output:

```
root@ubuntu:/# getent passwd|grep -P '^(nobody|root):'
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/sh
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/:/usr/sbin/nologin
root@ubuntu:/# cat /etc/passwd|grep -P '^(nobody|root):'
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

Curiously `getent shadow` doesn't show the same discrepancy:

```
root@ubuntu:/# getent shadow|grep -P '^(nobody|root):'
root:*:18697:0:99999:7:::
nobody:*:18697:0:99999:7:::
root@ubuntu:/# cat /etc/shadow|grep -P '^(nobody|root):'
root:*:18697:0:99999:7:::
nobody:*:18697:0:99999:7:::
```

Can someone please shed any light on what's happening here? Why is `getent passwd` producing two entries for `root` and `nobody` each?! Additionally, why does the shell for `root` differ for these entries?

Comment: I used a cloud image to have as pristine a state as possible and something that everyone could reproduce on their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the two entries is that `NSS` has both `passwd` and `systemd` as sources.

You can see this in the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file. The final two rows containing `root` and `nobody` that are returned by `getent passwd` are dynamic users that are created by `systemd` whereas the first instances of the two users are from `/etc/passwd`.